# Cannot read property 'allContentfulBlogPost' of undefined" after moving query from index.js to component in GatsbyJS (with Contenful and GraphQL)

Tags: components, graphql, gatsby, bulma, contentful

Moving a query from `index.js` to `midsection.js` (a component) gives Cannot read property of undefined.

I made a website with GatsbyJS which gets it's content from Contentful. I accomplished this by following the Build a blazing fast website with GatsbyJS and Contentful tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlIdop5Yv_Y

In the tutorial you learn the basics of making a query which shows your content from Contentful on the homepage.

Because I like to use Bulma and I'm pretty new to GatsbyJS (new to React as well) I decided to download the Gatsby-Bulma-Quickstart (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/amandeepmittal/gatsby-bulma-quickstart) and compare it to my own website and use what I need.

I decided to use the component structure used in the Quickstart and wanted to move the query for getting my content from the `index.js` to the `midsection.js`.

I got everything working until I moved the query.

My `index.js` looked like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
// import Layout from '../components/layout';

const BlogPost = ({node}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={node.slug}><h3>{node.title}</h3></Link>
      <img src={node.heroImage.resize.src} />
      <div>{node.description.childMarkdownRemark.excerpt}</div>
    </li>
  )
}

const IndexPage = ({data}) => (
  <ul className='blog-post'>
    {data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge) => <BlogPost node={edge.node} />)}
  </ul>
)

// const IndexPage = () => <Layout />;

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query pageQuery {
    allContentfulBlogPost (filter: {
      node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}
    },
    sort:{ fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          description {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              excerpt
            }
          }
          heroImage {
            resize(width: 300, height: 300) {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Note: This works, this shows my content. (But as you can see the components etc from the Quickstart are not included (yet))

This is what my `index.js` looks like right now:

```
import React from 'react'

import Layout from '../components/layout';


const IndexPage = () => <Layout />;

export default IndexPage
```

And this is what my `midsection.js` looks like right now:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'

import './style.scss'

const BlogPost = ({node}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={node.slug}><h3>{node.title}</h3></Link>
      <img src={node.heroImage.resize.src} />
      <div>{node.description.childMarkdownRemark.excerpt}</div>
    </li>
  )
}

const Midsection = ({data}) => (
  <ul className="blog-post">
    {data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge) => <BlogPost node={edge.node} />)}
  </ul>
)

export default Midsection

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query pageQuery {
    allContentfulBlogPost (filter: {
      node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}
    },
    sort:{ fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          description {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              excerpt
            }
          }
          heroImage {
            resize(width: 300, height: 300) {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Using this way of moving the query to a component gives this error in the browser:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulBlogPost' of undefined`

I'd expected to use the `midsection.js` component for columns to show available "blog posts" from Contentful. Instead this only works straight from `index.js`.

Is there some way the query is not working because I moved it from the root folder to the components folder? And if so, what do I need to do to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

**With an colleague helping me, we found an solution by following these steps:**

Change `layout.js` to:

```
import './style.scss'

const Layout = ({ children }) => children

export default Layout
```

Change `index.js` to:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Helmet from '../components/helmet';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Midsection from '../components/midsection';
import Footer from '../components/footer';

const IndexPage = ({data}) => (
  <Layout>
    <Helmet />
    <Header />
    <Midsection posts={data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges}/>
    <Footer />
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query pageQuery {
    allContentfulBlogPost (filter: {
      node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}
    },
    sort:{ fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          description {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              excerpt
            }
          }
          heroImage {
            resize(width: 300, height: 300) {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Change `midsection.js` to:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import './style.scss'

const BlogPost = ({node}) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={node.slug}><h3>{node.title}</h3></Link>
      <img src={node.heroImage.resize.src} />
      <div>{node.description.childMarkdownRemark.excerpt}</div>
    </li>
  )
}

const Midsection = ({ posts }) => (
  <ul className="blog-post">
    {posts.map(post => (
      <BlogPost key={post.node.slug} node={post.node} />
    ))}
  </ul>
)

export default Midsection
```

**So what was the problem and what solved it?**

The query used in this situation is a pageQuery which means that it only works from pages found in the pages folder. If you want to use the data in a component you have to pass it through :)

Comment: Yes, sure an object it was coming in to my Footer component `const Footer = ({ data })` Thanks